How do I easily share files with other users on the same computer?
On Windows I could easily create a share folder (and I could use the GUI to do this as well which was nice. I'm hoping there's a way to use the GUI to do this on Ubuntu?), if I put any files in this folder other users (on this same computer) would see this "share folder" and be able to access the files in it. Is there anything like this for Linux? Walk me through this step by step please and be very specific cause I get confused easily.
The name of my user is "Computer 1" and the second user is called "Computer 2"
I'm telling you this cause there is a space in these names and I'm a newbie but I remember one time I was running into problems with command line simply cause there was space in the name of one of my folders, and so the command wasn't working right, and then I figured out it's cause there was a space in the name of my folder, so if there's a space in the folder name you have to do this in the command, well if this is the folder name "Spring break pics" then in the command you have to do this 'Spring break pics' or something like that, this was a while ago so I can't remember anymore exactly but yeah, I do remember one time I couldn't get the command to work and then eventually I figured out it's cause there was a space in the folder name which will confuse command line if you don't use the proper syntax (it's called syntax right? I'm sorry I'm a newbie, I'm not a computer expert).
So yeah I do know if there's a space in the name it will confuse command line and so you have to use proper syntax around spaces in names of folders and whatnot, otherwise you'll run into trouble as I did. So this is why I want you to know there's a space in the user names on my computer.
And yeah before asking this question I tried googling to answer this question and honestly I'm just confused. I'm stumped.
Thanks for your time.
Edit: Someone recommended me this Share a Folder between two Local Users and in step 1 he tells you to go here How to manage users and groups using GUI? but it's many years old now, is the information still accurate?
Please understand I'm a newbie and I really just need someone to hold my hand and walk me through this step by step.  I mean it's telling me to install "gnome-system-tools" but is this information still accurate on Ubuntu 24.04? Does 24.04 require gnome system tools for managing groups?
And yeah if I can do this via GUI that would be fantastic. I'm much more comfortable with GUIs.
Edit 2: Yeah I just went into the App Center, you know the Ubuntu software store and searched for gnome system tools and it looks like it doesn't even exist anymore.
Is there a way to do this via GUI? I'm a lifelong Windows user who jumped over to Ubuntu a few years ago and honestly I really do prefer a GUI. Command line is just so confusing for me.
Edut 3: So if you go here Share a Folder between two Local Users it says
"Step Three: Verify that your brother can create delete files in the shared folder.
Let your brother login to the computer. Open Nautilus. It will open to your brother's home folder. Navigate to your home folder and open the shared folder by:
click on Computer or System Files (depends on the version of Ubuntu) on the left panel.
Double click on home folder, double click on folder named akumar inside home.
Create a file in the folder. Delete the new file."
Is this information still accurate on Ubuntu 24.04? Does that still work?
It says "It will open to your brother's home folder. Navigate to your home folder" like what, huh? And "click on Computer or System Files (depends on the version of Ubuntu) on the left panel." what, huh?
I'm confused. Can someone please help me understand this? So yeah I did
sudo apt install gnome-system-tools

and gnome system tools is indeed now installed on my PC and yeah it indeed looks like there is a way to add users to groups via a GUI, but yeah can someone tell me what to do from here? I prefer GUI.

@user68186 Come back and see my edit please.

@user68186 24.04 LTS

@user68186 Come back and look at my new edit please?

I have updated the answer to the linked question with pictures for Ubuntu 24.04.

@user68186 Hey I didn't realize you were the dude who originally answered that 11 years ago. Thanks for updating it. I'll see if it works here in a few days or so when I have time and if it works I'll let you know.
